# Xampp MySQL Is mysql always online?

Tags: mysql

Is Xampp online database or local database?
If i close Xampp and mysql, Will the database still work on my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAMPP is a local Webserver Apache + Database MySQL on your computer. It has literally nothing todo with your Website, except

- your Computer (the one running XAMPP) can be reached by the Internet via DynDNS or public IP.

If so, yes, your website will be offline after you shut down Apache or MySQL Services.

But since I assume, that your website runs on a dedicated webserver (with own MySQL Server) on the internet, it won't be affected by your local xampp development stack.